# transcluded content requires the controller of the transcluding directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which is transcluding it's content. And in the transcluded content is a directive which requires the controller of the transcluding directive. This throws an error if i'm creating a transclude function in the transcluding directive. I think this is because the transcluded content gets cloned when you provide a transclude function (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L846).

I also have a plunker describing my problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/rRKWW6zfjZuUiw1BY4zs?p=preview

What i want to do is i want to transclude the content and parse all of the transcluded content and then put it in the right place in the DOM and compile it myself. The transcluded content is actually the configuration for my directive.

I've also tried emptying the cloned array i receive in the transcluding function, because i actually don't need the content to be transcluded automatically. I just need to parse it and transclude it manually on a later point in time. Angular doesn't need to do anything with my transcluded content. But this doesn't work because the directives are already identified when the transcluding function is called. So when i empty the array i receive an error here (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L961).

kind regards,

Daan

Comment: If you want to deal with the content yourself, then why do you let it be transcluded in the first place?

Comment: because i don't want it in the DOM. I just want to receive it ... parse it and put it manually in the right place. Now i'm trying a solution without transcluding. But just doing the parsing and removing of the content manually in the compile phase of the directive.

Answer (score 10):

When you use `require: "^controller"` you are telling Angular that the directive requires `controller` to be attached to an ancestor DOM element at the time the link function is run.

When you do transclusion without using the ngTransclude directive, your parent directive link function get's passed a transclude method. (You already knew that; this is just for completeness.) This transclude method does the following:

1. Extracts the content for transclusion
2. If a `cloneAttachFn` was passed in, clone the content and call the cloneAttachFn
3. Calls `$compile()` to compile and link the content (or cloned content) using the scope supplied by the call to transclude (defaults to a new scope that inherits from the $parent of the directive scope).

If you call transclude, and end up not attaching the content as a descendant of an element with the required controller (or not adding the content to the DOM at all), then the content will have no parent with the required controller. Because it can't find the required controller, you get an error.

In your example, if you use kmBar with `require: "^kmFoo"`, you are restricted to adding the transcluded content to DOM nodes that are descendants of nodes that have kmFoo.

The easiest fix is to go ahead and append it to kmFoo's element for the purposes of $compile() and linking, but immediately [detach](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) it.

Detach (as opposed to [remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)) maintains click handlers, etc, so everything will continue to work if you append the element later.  If you are using early versions of AngularJS, you may need to include jQuery to get detach since it wasn't included in early versions of [jqLite](https://gist.github.com/esfand/9638882).

Here's a snippet of a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/1x8gCWUIu4vgIr59xcir?p=preview) I put together

```
app.directive('kmFoo', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    template: '<div></div>',
    transclude: true,
    controller: function() {
      // ...
    },
    link: function(scope, $element, attrs, ctrl, transcludeFn) {
      console.log('linking foo');
      // We are going to temporarily add it to $element so it can be linked,
      //  but after it's linked, we detach it.
      transcludeFn(scope, function(clone) {
        console.log('transcluding foo');
        $element.append(clone);
        c = clone;
      }).detach();// <- Immediately detach it
    }
  };
});

app.directive('kmBar', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    require: '^kmFoo',
    link: function(scope, $element, attrs, fooCtrl) {
      console.log('linking bar');
      // Right now it's a child of the element containing kmFoo,
      //  but it won't be after this method is complete.
      // You can defer adding this element to the DOM
      //  for as long as you want, and you can put it wherever you want.
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do need the transclude function? Is this not sufficient?

```
app.directive('kmFoo', function() {
  return {
    'restrict': 'A',
    'scope': true,
    'controller': function() {
      this.tryMe = function() { console.log("Success!") };
    },
    'link': function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      console.log('linking foo');
      var innerHtml = element.html();
      // do something with innerHtml
      element.html("<div>Empty</div>");
    }
  };
});

app.directive('kmBar', function() {
  return {
    'restrict': 'A',
    'scope': true,
    'require': '^kmFoo',
    'link': function(scope, element, attrs, fooCtrl) {
      fooCtrl.tryMe();
    }
  };
});
```

But if you really want to get access to the fooController and have a transclude function in kmFoo, you can access the controller via [`element.controller()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#methods) after all linking is done and all controllers are initialized.

```
app.directive('kmFoo', function() {
  return {
    'restrict': 'A',
    'scope': true,
    'template': '<div ng-transclude></div>',
    'transclude': true,
    'controller': function() {
      this.tryMe = function() { console.log("Success!") };
    },
    'link': function(scope, $element, attrs, ctrl, transcludeFn) {
      console.log('linking foo');
      // when you put the transclude function in comments it won't throw an error
      transcludeFn(scope, function(clone) {
        console.log('transcluding foo');
      });
    }
  };
});

app.directive('kmBar', function() {
  return {
    'restrict': 'A',
    'scope': true,
    'template': "<button ng-click='tryMe()'>Feeling lucky?</button>",
    'link': function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.getFooCtrl = function() { 
        return element.parent().controller('kmFoo'); 
      };
      console.log('linking bar');
      console.log('parent not yet known: ' + element.parent().toString());
    },
    'controller': function($scope) {
      $scope.tryMe = function() {
        $scope.getFooCtrl().tryMe();
      };
    }
  };
});
```

See it in action with [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/zlZRFAJuOjsxcY8qZ442?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

To perform this without having it displayed in the DOM, you can use a

```
 transclude: 'element'
```

on the second directive.

This will avoid using some tricks to get the information you need.

```
app.directive('kmFoo', function() {
  return {
    'restrict': 'A',
    'scope': true,
    'template': '<div ng-transclude></div>',
    'transclude': true,
    'controller': function() {

    },
    'link': function(scope, $element, attrs, ctrl, transcludeFn) {
      console.log('linking foo');
      // when you put the transclude function in comments it won't throw an error
      //transcludeFn(scope, function(clone) {
      //  console.log('transcluding foo');
      //});
    }
  };
});

app.directive('kmBar', function() {
  return {
    'restrict': 'A',
    'scope': {},
    'require': '^kmFoo',
    'link': function(scope, $element, attrs, fooCtrl) {
      console.log('linking bar');
    }
  };
});

app.directive('kmBarWithElement', function() {
  return {
    'restrict': 'A',
    'scope': {},
    'transclude': 'element',
    'require': '^kmFoo',
    'link': function(scope, $element, attrs, fooCtrl, transclude) {
      transclude(function(clone) {
        console.log('here the element: ', clone);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Here is a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/lbT7oz74Yz7IZvEKp77T?p=preview